# Without refreshing page, changing value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page, the menu comes from menu.ascx in masterpage.

> Menu includes below items:
>
> - Request(5)
> - Info

In menu.ascx.cs, I calculate 5. It comes from a SQL query like

```
Select Count(*) From Request Where Id = 1; //returns 5
```

For instance;
in other page, I edit any record and the result of query will be 6.
But without refreshing page it does not change and still seems 5.

Are there any way to do it without refreshing page except for Ajax solutions?
When I edited any record can I refresh all page?

Comment: Any solution to this will be AJAX-based. Is that a problem?

Comment: I wonder are there any solution except for Ajax.

Comment: @StackUser Nope - either full page refresh or partial content loading via AJAX calls.

Comment: @StackUser Indeed. You want to refresh just a part of the page, that's AJAX (ok, *very* simply put).

Comment: Why would you not want to use AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get that updated in the browser without resorting to either one of these options:

- **full page refresh** (postback)
- **ajax** (either via the provided server controls like UpdatePanel or via plain self written javascript ajax calls, ps: think jQuery to smoothen this process)

A newer approach would be to make use of [**Websockets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets) where you can push data from the server to the client. Microsoft has created a cool library, with various fallback scenarios, in [**SignalR**](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SignalR).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the HTML you want refreshed in an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx), which will allow partial page updates.  It is an AJAX-based solution, but *there is no way to perform a partial page update with information from the server without using AJAX*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the [XmlHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) object that is available in JavaScript. You can embed the script in your web page via the usual methods.

[An example can be found here](http://www.hendricksongroup.com/code_call_web_service_javascript.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would say AJAX is a well known option here to update partial page.